# Não consigo acessar o localhost em outra máquina da rede

Tags: apache, redes, localhost, easyphp

Estou tentando acessar o localhost (ip: 192.168.0.11) através de outra máquina da rede.
Inicio o Apache com acesso na porta 8080 (com o EasyPHP Devserver 16.1) e digito no browser de outra máquina da rede (ip: 192.168.0.15) o endereço "http://192.168.0.11:8080/site". A página fica carregando até dar timeout e eu nunca consigo acessar.
Já liberei a porta 8080 no firewall do windows 10, mas não adiantou.
Alguém teria alguma ideia do porque não funciona?

Obs: quando eu desabilito o firewall do localhost e tento acessar por outra máquina, a conexão é recusada ao invés de dar timeout.

Comment: Precisa ver  no arquivo do apache se ele pode receber requisições de outras maquinas que não sejam a local

Comment: Ok. Você saberia me dizer qual arquivo? Eu não entendo muito bem disso. Simplesmente instalei o EasyPHP e comecei a usar sem necessidades de fazer configurações complexas.

Comment: Pode começar com [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24011132/1342547), lembre de reiniciar o apache após qualquer alteração no arquivo.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Funcionou agora. Valeu de mais!!!

Comment: @Breno Macena, fecha a pergunta se a questão foi resolvido.

Comment: "localhost" nunca será acessado de outra máquina de rede, está havendo um problema de terminologia. Se você quer o 192.168.0.11, não quer o localhost (que, inclusive, por padrão é 127.0.0.1)